# Pass params to props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I'm using [React Select](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select) and I would like to pass `url` as param to `loadOptions`. So, I would something like :

```
<Select.Async {...input} loadOptions={ getOptions(url) }/>
```

and this is my `getOptions` :

```
const getOptions = ((input, callback) => {
  return fetch("http://reqres.in/api/users") // Get my url HERE
    .then((res) => {
      return res.json();
    }).then((json) => {
      return {options: json.data};
    });
});
```

Is there anyway to achieve this ? Thanks in advance.

**SOLUTION :**

The easiest solution would look like :

```
<Select.Async {...input} loadOptions={ getOptions.bind(url) }/>
```

and put `this` instead of the url in `getOptions`

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: seeing as getting the options is asynchronous you might have to set the URL in the state, then update it once getOptions() returns

Answer (score 0):

If the url is fixed, make it a constant in your component and access that constant from within your loadOptions function.

If it is variable, you should store it in the state of your component and update it accordingly via
`setState(url, 'http://...')`. Access it with `this.state.url` within loadOptions. Hovever, this use case seems like your are doing something wrong. Maybe you can describe your use case more clearly?